# How can I choose shared library I need when has 2 share libraries in the file?

Tags: windows, dll, makefile, dynamic-linking

There are two shared libraries that are the same name but different suffixes. eg. (A.dll and A.lib). Now when I use the command “make” to make C codes, the compiler chooses the A.lib as the default option. Then how can I choose the flexibly library I need? And the following code is the code of makefile.

```
CC = gcc

COSI_LIB = '/C/A'

OBJ_NAME = B.exe
SOURCE =  B.c

${OBJ_NAME}: ${SOURCE}
    @$(CC) -I${COSI_LIB} -L${COSI_LIB} -lA -o ${OBJ_NAME} ${SOURCE}

clean:
    @rm $(OBJ_NAME) -r -f
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? Your question appears to show fundamental misunderstanding or how `DLL`s and `LIB`s work.

Comment: @EmployedRussian yes, I compile file on Windows.  And I need to know that When there are two same name files but different format (ex. One named abc.dll and another named abc.lib) and I input command ‘*make*’ on term, I wish that compiler select .dll file  instead of .lib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to know that When there are two same name files but different format (ex. One named abc.dll and another named abc.lib) and I input command ‘make’ on term, I wish that compiler select .dll file instead of .lib file.

First, the *compiler* doesn't care about any `.lib` or `.dll` files, only the *linker* does.

Second, on Windows, the linker *never* uses `.dll`s. It always uses `.lib`, and it is the `.lib` file which contains *either* `.o` files (which are linked directly into your binary), *or* "dll imports", which tell the linker to build "import tables" to be used at runtime to import the functions from a corresponding `.dll`.

That is (unlike on UNIX) you *don't get to decide* whether to link against `.lib` or `.dll` (you *always* link against `.lib`). Whoever built the `.lib` and the `.dll` decided which (if any) parts are to be linked in directly, and which are to be imported from the `.dll`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing my mistakes. First, I mix **compiler** up with **linker**. Second, ‘.lib’ file link to binary file (ex. Exe file on windows) and ‘.dll’ is dynamically used in executable file when the file is working.